# Why application crashes when starting activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, android-activity

I'm totally new to eclipse and android. I'm trying to use a button to start a new activity. Whenever I click the button, the application crashes. Please assist.

The code in layout-->activity_main.xml is as follows:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/logComplaint"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="getComplaint"
            android:text="@string/logComplaint" />
```

The code in MainActivity.java is as follows:

```
// --- When LogComplaint button is clicked---      
    public void getComplaint (View V){
        //---Change Form View Log Complaint form---
        Intent nextComplaint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogComplaint.class);
        startActivity (nextComplaint);
    }
```

The code in AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<activity android:name=".logComplaint"></activity>
```

Lastly, the code in the new class is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class LogComplaint extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logcomplaintform);  
    }   
}
```

Comment: please post the log with the exception, too

Comment: Where is your stacktrace? Make sure  you are use `LogComplaint` in your manifest.

Comment: `android:name=".logComplaint"` and `LogComplaint.class ` Do not you think that they are different?

Answer (score 1):

Change Activity Name from `logComplaint` to `LogComplaint` in your `Manifest` activity declaration part.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line:

```
<activity android:name=".logComplaint"></activity>
```

to:

```
<activity android:name="your.package.name.LogComplaint"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use -

```
Intent nextComplaint = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogComplaint.class);
startActivity (nextComplaint);
instead of  
Intent nextComplaint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogComplaint.class);
startActivity (nextComplaint);
```

Also make sure you have declared LogComplaint activity in manifest file.